# HTML/CSS Browser Issues

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, cross-platform

I am running across an issue I quite don't understand. I am testing different things via Chrome on my PC and Chrome on my Nook Tablet. Example, I'm testing out word-spacing on my PC in Chrome and everything lines up the way I want it to. However, on my Nook Tablet it looks different, as if the spacing isn't enough.

You can check it out at [www.innerstyles.net/testtest.html](http://www.innerstyles.net/testtest.html) if you want to see them on different devices or view the images I uploaded.

This comes from my PC and how I want it to look like.
pc image.

[image]

This comes from the Nook HD Tablet and is not how I want it to be.
nook image.

[image]

My HTML is obviously basic with a div named #testdiv.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />


<title>Test - testtest</title>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css" />  

</head>
<body>

<div id="testdiv">
```

test1 test2 test3 test4

```
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS.

```
#testdiv {
    width:200px;
    background:#888; 
    color:#fff; 
    text-align:right; 
    word-spacing:3px; 
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```

The PC Chrome browser renders it differently from the Mobile Chrome browser.

So my question is how do I fix this so everything looks the same via PC or Mobile? I've tried implementing different widths, fonts, HTML reset such as normalize but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: In my Safari, it looks more like your Nook.  Seems like you have some invalid HTML or CSS someplace.  You also have done a poor job of explaining the actual spacing issue… what's happening and what you want to happen.

Comment: The problem is the text on the Nook is not flushed from one side to the other like it is seen on PC. The Nook image shows additional space to the left inside the DIV, but not on PC. I would like the "test" text flushed from one side to the other on the Nook as well, eliminating the empty DIV space. Kind of like text-align:justify, but I know that will not work. I tried the webkit-text-size-adjust but that did not do anything.

Comment: You have a fixed width and you're pushing the text to the right… of course any remaining space is going to be on the left.  This is because every device and browser is going to render fonts slightly differently.

Comment: BTW… also show the relevant HTML markup.

Comment: Thank you Sparky for responding with me. Here is the HTML markup which is very tiny since I am just testing stuff out.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        
        
    
   <title>Test - testtest</title>  
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css" />  
            
            
                    
 </head>

<body>

<div id="testdiv">
test1 test2 test3 test4
</div>


</body>
</html>

Comment: Please take the critical information from your last two comments and edit it into your OP.

Comment: Sorry I am new to Stackoverflow. I am slowly learning this fantastic site. I edited everything to to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line so it won't mess with fonts on mobile browsers:

**

> -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;

**

Comment: I tried this as well and it did not work unfortunately.